# The probability that a process signals (simple conditional probability)

Tags: statistics, conditional-probability, signal-processing

I have this problem (from Montgomery's *Applied Probability and Statistics*, 5th Edition, problem 2-145, if anyone wants to see the original problem) but it's long, so for the sake of brevity I'll give a smaller version of the problem--if I can see how to solve the smaller version I'm sure I could figure out the bigger one.

Problem: Suppose a test claims 99% accuracy of detecting $A$ and 98% accuracy of detecting $B$, and 97% accuracy of detecting $C$.  A collection of samples is formed, such that 40% of the samples contain $A$, 30% contain $B$, and 20% contain $C$.  "The process signals if all categories $A$ through $C$ are present."  Find the probability that the process signals, and then find the probability that $A$ is present given the process signaled.

Now that sounds like it must be a sloppy way of expressing the problem, because if the process signals then every category is present and therefore, conditional on the process signaling, $A$ is present with 100% probability.  I'm guessing, instead, what should go in the place of the quoted sentence is "The process signals if all categories are detected by the test."

In that case it seems to me that we would find the probability that the test is positive for $A$, which is $P(A+) = P(A+|A)P(A)+P(A+|A')P(A')$, right?  I think the accuracy statement tells me $P(A+|A)=0.99$, but how would I get $P(A+|A')$?  Or am I just interpreting the whole question the wrong way?

Comment: When you say 40% of the samples contain A, and 30% contain B, etc., is the chance of containing A independent of the chance of containing B? Also you are wrong to say that A is present with 100% probability. We are told that the test is only 99% accurate, and we are also told that a positive indicates that B and C are detected.

Comment: @SuzuHirose I assume the events are independent, but it's not specified in the problem.  And my point was, the way the problem stated it, the "process signals" if all categories are present--not if the categories are detected by the test.  So it wouldn't matter what the accuracy of the test is.  If it signals, all categories are present, so category $A$ is present with 100% probability.

Comment: If this is the way the problem is stated in the book I am glad I don't have to use this book.

Comment: Also "99% accuracy of detecting $A$" is a bit weird, it means $P(DA|A)=0.99$, so $P({\overline{DA}}|A)=0.01$, but what about $P({\overline{DA}}|A)$ and $P(DA|{\overline A})$?

Comment: @Suzu Hirose That's my question too. I guess the question as stated is not sufficiently defined.